# Overleaf Latex: Create Table with Multiple Columns and Multiple Rows w/Sub-rows

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to create the following table in LaTex with the exact layout shown below.

[image]

I also want to have the following Latex statements in my table code.  They allow me to set a caption and label, respectively according to the formatting of a specific journal.

```
%   \caption{Model Execution Summary}
%   \label{tab:tablelabel}
```

I have scoured Google and tried many different solutions but none of them can produce even close to the layout of my desired table.  I am also new to LaTex so this is a struggle.

Can someone show me how to do this in Latex please?

Comment: If you tried many solutions, you should show at least one of them by adding a compilable [mre] to your question.

Comment: Retyping text from an image is not something which makes it attractive to answer your question.

Comment: Got it, I'll show the minimal reproducible example

Comment: Also [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Model Execution Summary}
\label{tab:tablelabel}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|} 
\cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & Algorithm & Column Shapes & Column Pair Trends & Quality Score\\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Category 1546} & \textbf{Gaussian Copula} & \textbf{87.22\%} &\textbf{71.25\%} & \textbf{79.23\%} \\
                                   & CTGAN Neural Network     & 77.00\% & 79.96\% & 78.48\% \\
                                   & CopulaGAN Neural Network & 75.92\% & 74.23\% & 75.08\% \\
                                   & TVAE Autoencoders        & 72.66\% & 74.27\% & 73.46\% \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Category 155} & \textbf{Gaussian Copula} &\textbf{91.57\%} & \textbf{80.17\%} & \textbf{85.87\%} \\
                                  & CTGAN Neural Network & 84.14\% & 80.79\% & 82.47\% \\
                                  & CopulaGAN Neural Network & 84.09\% & 80.56\% & 82.32\% \\
    & TVAE Autoencoders & 85.50\% & 85.13\% & 85.41\% \\
    \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Category 8909} & \textbf{Gaussian Copula} & \textbf{95.64\%} & \textbf{81.96\%} &\textbf{88.80\%} \\
                               & CTGAN Neural Network & 81.15\% & 79.84\% & 80.50\% \\
                               & CopulaGAN Neural Network & 81.24\% & 82.18\% & 81.71\% \\
                               & TVAE Autoencoders & 75.98\% &75.54\%& 75.76\% \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Category 8189} &\textbf{Gaussian Copula} & \textbf{95.08\%} & \textbf{82.63\%} & \textbf{88.86\%} \\
                                   & CTGAN Neural Network & 79.43\% & 85.87\% & 82.65\% \\
                                   & CopulaGAN Neural Network & 78.82\% & 83.60\% & 81.21\% \\
                                   & TVAE Autoencoders & 75.47\% & 77.57\% & 76.52\% \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Category 4162} & \textbf{Gaussian Copula} & \textbf{86.86\%} & \textbf{13.64\%} & \textbf{50.25\%} \\
                                   &CTGAN Neural Network & 86.62\% & 11.71\% & 49.16\% \\
                                   & CopulaGAN Neural Network & 87.60\% & 11.83\% & 49.71\% \\
                                   & TVAE Autoencoders & 86.20\% & 10.91\% & 48.55\% \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

With the following output
[image]

`the exact layout shown below` leads to the following twerks:

- using the landscape package, due to its size
- using the the `multicolumn{1}{r|}{}` to achive that cell in the up right corner has no borders